# The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController with nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

i want to display most viewed category wise product in category home page using plugin.

i added code for that in controller

```
ProductMostviewedController.cs:

[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult CategoryHomepageCategorywiseMostViewedProduct(int categoryid, int? productThumbPictureSize)
        {
            var categoryProduct = _productService.CategorywiseMostViewProduct(categoryid);
            var model = PrepareProductOverviewModels(categoryProduct, true, true, productThumbPictureSize)
                .ToList();
            return View("../Views/Catalog/CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml",model);
        }

        [NonAction]
```

i has already write code in `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml`

```
@Html.Action("CategoryHomepageCategorywiseMostViewedProduct", "ProductMostviewedController", new { categoryid = Model.Id })
```

but i was got an error :

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - The controller for path '/jewelry' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

so please tell me what 's problem?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a `public class JewelryController : Controller { ...` ?

Comment: no..but i have  public class ProductMostviewedController : BaseNopController{....}

Comment: Is `BaseNopController` a `Controller` or does it otherwise implement `IController`...

Comment: i was try both but same result i was got

Comment: BaseNopController is inherits from Controller... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Html.Action("CategoryHomepageCategorywiseMostViewedProduct", 
"ProductMostviewedController", new { categoryid = Model.Id })
```

I saw you put "**ProductMostviewedControlller**", which should actually be "**ProductMostviewed**" (without the word **Controller**).

:)